# How do I draw the values from Gson that i get to google map direction polyline on the map?

Tags: json, google-maps, directions, android, gson

1.package com.example.user.batroomapp;

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.user.batroomapp.gsontopojo.MyPojo;
import com.example.user.batroomapp.gsontopojo.Routes;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

2. im do the class from Json to Gson and now i dont know how to contiume. plese help me im stuck.

   public class DirectionJson extends AppCompatActivity  {

   ```
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);


       }
       String apiKeyDirection = "My Api Direction";

               public static class JsonTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, List<Routes>> {

               @Override
               protected List<Routes> doInBackground(String... params) {
                       HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                       BufferedReader reader = null;
                       URL url;
                       {
                               try {
                                       url = new URL(params[0]);
                                       connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                                       InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                                       reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                                       StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                                       String line = "";
                                       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                               buffer.append(line);
                                               Log.d("aaa",""+line);
                                       }
                                       Gson gson=new Gson();
                                       MyPojo myPojo =gson.fromJson(line,MyPojo.class);
                                       for (Routes routes:myPojo.getRoutes());


                                       String finalJason = buffer.toString();
                                       JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJason);
                                       JSONArray parentArrey = parentObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                                       List<Routes>routeslist = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   //                                        JSONArray parentArrey2 = parentObject.getJSONArray("geocoded_waypoints");
                                           for (int i = 0; i

   ```
                                         routeslist.add(routes);
                                       }
                                       return routeslist;

                               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                               } catch (IOException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                               } catch (JSONException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                               } finally {
                                       if (connection != null) {
                                               connection.disconnect();
                                       }
                                       try {
                                               if (reader != null) {
                                                       reader.close();
                                               }
                                       } catch (IOException e) {
                                               e.printStackTrace();
                                       }

                               }
                       }
                       return null;
               }

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(List<Routes> result) {

                       super.onPostExecute(result);
                       Log.d("json",result.toString());
                       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                      // MyPojo myPoj = gson.fromJson(result, MyPojo.class);
                       //Log.d("bbb", myPoj.toString());

               }

               private void parseJson(String data){
                       if (data==null)
                               return;

               }

       }
   ```

   }

   3. this is the on click

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ```
      setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);
      // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
      final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
              .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
      mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
      Button bDriving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDriving);


      bDriving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              new DirectionJson.JsonTask().execute
                      ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sydney" +
                              ",au&destination=perth,au&waypoints=via:-37.81223%2C144.96254%7Cvia:" +
                              "-34.92788%2C138.60008&key=" + apiKeyDirection);

          }
      });
      ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how i draw the Gson Value to polyline google map direction on the Google Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591144/how-i-draw-the-gson-value-to-polyline-google-map-direction-on-the-google-map)

Comment: its not an answer.

Comment: It's a duplicate of your own question. You posted two same question. I edited the other one.